# Impartial Games with Multiple Optimal Strategies

Tags: combinatorics, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

Impartial games such as Nim, and Neutral Tic-Tac-Toe all seem to have one single optimal strategy. I wondered what impartial games created have more than one optimal strategy. Or whether all impartial games simply only have one optimal strategy. Thanks for answering!

Comment: Often, even Nim has multiple optimal strategies. If the pile sizes are [8,9,10,11,12], then there exists a winning move on every one of the piles. For Tic-Tac-Toe, optimal play leads to a draw, but the first player has several non-isomorphic options for how the draw plays out.

Comment: The answer to this may depend on what exactly you mean by a "single optimal strategy".  If you mean there's exactly one winning move for the player in a winning position, this isn't true even for Nim.  Did you mean something else?

Answer (score 2):

Nim can have multiple optimal strategies. For instance, if the initial heaps are of sizes $1,2,3,3$, then one optimal strategy is removing a single chip from the heap of 2, (yielding $1,1,3,3$) and another is to remove a heap of 3.